# Using Lucene 9.10.0 MemoryIndex in Java to ingest and search IntField and use rangequery

Tags: lucene, full-text-search, elasticsearch-analyzers

I am trying to overcome integer range query problem with MemoryIndex. ingesting 2 fields status which is string field and portno which is int field. If the port range is within 50 to 90, input should match. When I am using String representation of portno, getting unwanted results due to number indexed as String. But when I try to use IntField for portno, it is not matching valid numbers within range too. Code and output as follows:

Criteria: status: Open AND portno: [50 TO 90]

portno: 4 Criteria matched: false

portno: 5 Criteria matched: false

portno: 6 Criteria matched: true

portno: 7 Criteria matched: true

portno: 8 Criteria matched: true

portno: 9 Criteria matched: true

portno: 49 Criteria matched: false

portno: 50 Criteria matched: true

portno: 89 Criteria matched: true

portno: 90 Criteria matched: true

portno: 91 Criteria matched: false

portno: 100 Criteria matched: false

=>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>

Criteria: status: Open AND portno: [50 TO 90]

portno: 4 Criteria matched: false

portno: 5 Criteria matched: false

portno: 6 Criteria matched: false

portno: 7 Criteria matched: false

portno: 8 Criteria matched: false

portno: 9 Criteria matched: false

portno: 49 Criteria matched: false

portno: 50 Criteria matched: false

portno: 89 Criteria matched: false

portno: 90 Criteria matched: false

portno: 91 Criteria matched: false

portno: 100 Criteria matched: false

```
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.core.WhitespaceAnalyzer;
import org.apache.lucene.document.Field;
import org.apache.lucene.document.IntField;
import org.apache.lucene.index.memory.MemoryIndex;
import org.apache.lucene.queryparser.classic.MultiFieldQueryParser;
import org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher;
import org.apache.lucene.search.Query;
import org.apache.lucene.search.TopDocs;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;


public class CriteriaEvaluatorTest {

    private static void indexNumberAsString() {
        List<Integer> ilist = List.of(4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 49, 50, 89, 90, 91, 100);
        String criteria = "status: Open AND portno: [50 TO 90]";
        System.out.println("Criteria: " + criteria);
        ilist.forEach(number -> {
                    MemoryIndex memoryIndex = new MemoryIndex();
                    WhitespaceAnalyzer analyzer = new WhitespaceAnalyzer();
                    Map<String, Object> fmap = new HashMap<>();
                    fmap.put("status", "Open");
                    fmap.put("portno", String.valueOf(number));
                    for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : fmap.entrySet()) {
                        String fldName = entry.getKey();
                        String fldValue = entry.getValue().toString();
                        memoryIndex.addField(fldName, fldValue, analyzer);
                    }
                    IndexSearcher indexSearcher = memoryIndex.createSearcher();
                    String[] fldArray = new String[3];
                    int j = 0;
                    for (String fld : fmap.keySet()) {
                        fldArray[j++] = fld;
                    }
                    MultiFieldQueryParser multiFieldQueryParser = new MultiFieldQueryParser(fldArray, analyzer);
                    try {
                        Query query = multiFieldQueryParser.parse(criteria);
                        TopDocs topDocs = indexSearcher.search(query, 1);
                        boolean result = topDocs.totalHits.value > 0;
                        System.out.println("portno: " + number + " Criteria matched: " + result);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        String message = e.getMessage();
                    }
                }
        );
    }

    private static void indexNumberAsIntPoint() {
        List<Integer> ilist = List.of(4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 49, 50, 89, 90, 91, 100);
        String criteria = "status: Open AND portno: [50 TO 90]";
        System.out.println("Criteria: " + criteria);
        ilist.forEach(number -> {
                    MemoryIndex memoryIndex = new MemoryIndex(true, true);
                    WhitespaceAnalyzer analyzer = new WhitespaceAnalyzer();
                    Map<String, Object> fmap = new HashMap<>();
                    fmap.put("status", "Open");
                    fmap.put("portno", number);
                    for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : fmap.entrySet()) {
                        String fldName = entry.getKey();
                        String fldValue = entry.getValue().toString();
                        if (fldName.equals("portno")) {
                            IntField intField = new IntField("portno", number, Field.Store.YES);
                            memoryIndex.addField(intField, analyzer);
                        } else {
                            memoryIndex.addField(fldName, fldValue, analyzer);
                        }
                    }
                    IndexSearcher indexSearcher = memoryIndex.createSearcher();
                    String[] fldArray = new String[3];
                    int j = 0;
                    for (String fld : fmap.keySet()) {
                        fldArray[j++] = fld;
                    }
                    MultiFieldQueryParser multiFieldQueryParser = new MultiFieldQueryParser(fldArray, analyzer);
                    try {
                        Query query = multiFieldQueryParser.parse(criteria);
                        TopDocs topDocs = indexSearcher.search(query, 1);
                        boolean result = topDocs.totalHits.value > 0;
                        System.out.println("portno: " + number + " Criteria matched: " + result);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        String message = e.getMessage();
                    }
                }
        );
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        indexNumberAsString();
        System.out.println("=>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>");
        indexNumberAsIntPoint();
    }
```

Comment: If you try adding an `IntField` to your `MemoryIndex`, the term gets ignored. You can see this for yourself by dumping the index contents using `memoryIndex.toStringDebug()`. The [documentation](https://lucene.apache.org/core/9_10_0/memory/org/apache/lucene/index/memory/MemoryIndex.html) mentions that this type of index contains "a name and a **fulltext** value" (emphasis mine). Your `IntField` is not a fulltext field. I'm surprised it gets ignored - as opposed to throwing an exception.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know a way around this, for this type of query against this type of index. I suspect this scenario is not what `MemoryIndex` was designed for. Maybe someone else has a solution, though.

Comment: Thank you @andrewJames yes, I tried `memoryIndex.toStringDebug()` but it showed token count 0 for `IntField`, I was expecting exception but seems it is silently ignoring it.

Comment: I think this probably makes sense - because what is the point of trying to perform an integer range query on a single Lucene document containing text values? I don't know the wider context of your question, but you should probably just process the source data using Java, before it is indexed by Lucene (or even instead of using Lucene), given what you are trying to do.

Comment: Yes, I agree, but I have a very specific requirement which I am trying to implement using this hack-ish way. I have policy processing engine with input policies and events from user, do-this if-this-criteria-matches, so indexing incoming event in MemoryIndex, searching it, if hits>1, criteria matched-execute action, else skip processing.

Answer (score 1):

Found solution:

1. While adding fields in `MemoryIndex`, add as `LongField` (or `IntField`):

```
if(LONG_FIELDS.contains(fldName)) {
  LongField longField = new LongField(fldName, Long.valueOf(fldValue), Field.Store.YES);
  memoryIndex.addField(longField, analyzer);
} else {
  memoryIndex.addField(fldName, fldValue, analyzer);
}
```

2. Add a custom parser:
   So for specific Long/Int Fields, range queries are working properly.

```
public class CustomCriteriaParser extends MultiFieldQueryParser {
  public CustomCriteriaParser(String[] f, List<String> lflist, Analyzer a) {
    super(f, a);
    if (Utils.notNullAndEmpty(lflist)) {
      this.longFields.addAll(lflist);
    }
  }
            
  private List<String> longFields = new ArrayList<>();
            
  protected Query getFieldQuery(String field, String queryText, boolean quoted) {
    return newRangeQuery(field, queryText, queryText, true, true);
  }
            
  protected Query newRangeQuery(String field, String fromValue, String toValue, boolean startInclusive, boolean endInclusive) {
    if (this.longFields.contains(field)) {
      return LongField.newRangeQuery(field, Long.valueOf(fromValue), Long.valueOf(toValue));
    }
    return (TermRangeQuery) super.newRangeQuery(field, fromValue, toValue, startInclusive, endInclusive);
  }
}
```